# Enable C99 in Qt Creator

Tags: c, gcc, qt-creator

I've created a Plain C project in Qt Creator in Linux, but I'm getting this error:

```
error: 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code
```

What should I put in my *.pro file to enable C99?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS += -std=c99
```

This worked for me, even though it is not documented and the intellisense doesn't recognize it.

Answer (score 3):

You could set [QMAKE_CC](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-cc) or `QMAKE_CFLAGS_DEBUG` and `QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE` to contain `-std=c99`, e.g. add into your `.pro` file

```
 QMAKE_CC= gcc -std=c99
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, when I tried with `QMAKE_CFLAGS += -std=c99`, it worked, even though it is not documented and the intellisense doesn't recognize it.